# While True statement in previous function running. Why?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to make a pretty simple text choice based game to learn python. After running through to the very end, I am hit with the while loop I created earlier and I'm not sure how that works. Can someone explain the path that the computer is taking?

My code is here:

```
def dead(message):
    print message, "You have lost, but you can try again if you'd like."
    exit(0)

def start():
    print """You're sitting in a dark room. You hear the dull hum of the engine and coughing
from what seems to be like 50 or more people. The last thing you remember was walking out
of a convenience store before you felt a sharp pain at the back of your head and blacked out.
You're years of tactical army training tell you that you must've gotten kidnapped. There's a sack
over your head to prevent you from seeing anything. You feel a collar on your neck...There's a
faint beeping. What do you do? Take off the collar? Or wait to see what is happening?"""
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if "take off" in choice:
            dead("Your hands are free and you pull off the collar. The beeping stops, but then the collar explodes...killing you instantly. You had no idea it was a bomb attached to your neck.")

        elif "wait" in choice:
            print """You decide to wait it out. That collar might even be a bomb on your neck.
All of a sudden the bag is taken off your head by an unknown figure. You see 50+ people
looking around just as confused as you. Just as you are about to say something, the floor opens up
and all of you fall through. You're now in freefall. \n"""
            freefall()

        else:
            print "You need to decide."


def freefall():
    print """As you fall, you hear the other people screaming on the way down. However, with your calm
composure and army training you realize everyone is equipped with a parachute. The ground is still far
away and you try to look around to orient yourself. You and all the others seem to be dropping into a island
with a giant active volcano in the middle. Out of nowhere, the collar begins to speak to you.

\"Welcome to the Trial. I, the host, have left weapons scattered throughout the island. There is only one out of all
of you that I will return to their normal lives. The rest of you will die here. If you attempt to leave the island, the
collar will detonate. As I said before, only one of you will be taken back...you know what that means\"

You aren't surprised. You've seen the Hunger Games. With the wind blowing past you, you look to the East and see buildings.
To the West, you see care packages being dropped. No doubt there are weapons at both locations that you can loot. Which direction
do you want to aim for?
"""
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if "east" in choice or "East" in choice:
        print "You decide to drift towards the East where you saw the buildings. There must be weapons there."

    elif "west" in choice or "West" in choice:
        print "You decide to drift towards the West where there are care packages dropping. There must be weapons there."

    else:
        dead("You decided not to drop in the East or West. A giant hand slaps you out of the sky and you hit the ground and die instantly")




start()
```

For example, I type "wait" and then "west". I was expecting the program to end after printing "You decide to drift towards the West where there are care packages dropping. There must be weapons there", but instead I am taken back to the raw_input prompt in the start() function.

It's odd because the initial print statement in the start() function is not executed. I must have a flawed understanding of how to format levels. I thought the while True loop would end once I left the function that contained the while True loop. Can someone explain why the while loop is still running and how I can avoid this mistake in the future? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: To exit a loop use `break`, to exit a function the use `return`.  When you wish to exit the function in this case just do a `break` on the conditions you wish to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once python is done executing the `freefall()` function, it goes back to where the function was called (so the `elif` statement). It will ignore the `else` statement and start over at the beginning of the `while True` statement (so at `choice = raw_input("> ")`)

If you're having trouble understanding the flow of code, i can recommend using http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html to see the code executed step  by step.